# What identifies an entity in Axibase?

Tags: database, time-series, axibase

Official [doc said that the ID is the PK of an entity](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/schema.html), while I found the `name` is the unique field for an entity.

Which one is the unique identifier?

Screenshot:
[image]